# What is the use of this diode in Kelly controller wiring?

Tags: diodes

[image]

I need help in this circuit.

I want to know the use of this diode here.

This is a diode for 4000W motor controller.

If I want to calculate the needed one for 1000W, what are the equations?

Comment: It's a flyback diode and its value is unrelated to the capacity of the switching contacts.

Answer (score 3):

The diode is protecting whatever is switching the relay coil. It has nothing to do with the power of the motor or the output capability of the "Kelly controller".

See [Flyback diode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyback_diode) for more.

Answer (score 1):

The coil inductance stores energy \$E=1/2*LI^2[J]\$

The 3A diode is rated for a max current spike and energy dissipation pulse. The junction temp rise increases with L or I due to diode ESR which is inverse with I max rating typically, ESR <= 1/Pmax.

A 3A 1N5406RLG  diode has an absolute max current rating fora non-repetitive pulse of 300A. So this is fine.

The only part affected by a larger load is the switched contact arc during turn off and contact ratings are de-rated for inductive loads for this reason and 1k 10W was the snubber selected for this. Increasing the current thus increases the voltage drop across the 1k during flyback and self-heating results for each contact bounce.

The 1k Resistor permits a higher voltage drop and thus a faster switching time T=L/R than the diode. So limits for voltage and current affect the choice of snubber for various L, I loads.